# Override Kendo grid navigation TAB key to Enter Key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

When i hit the tab key Kendo grid UI automatically focus and put the next column in to Edit mode.What i need is to do the same thing when i enter the ENTER key.
Is there any way to Override the Tab key function with enter Key

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the same class to your columns. Then you can do this in jQuery:

```
$('.columnClass input').keypress(function() {
    if(event.which === 13) {
        var nextItem = $(this).next('.columnClass input');

        if( nextItem.size() === 0 ) {
            nextItem = $('.columnClass input').eq(0);
        }

        nextItem.focus();
   }
});
```

13 is the keycode for enter button